# Pattern matching against a tuple

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match against a tuple constructed from a deconstructed enum variant like this:

```
enum Enum {
  Var {
    field1: Option<String>,
    field2: Option<String>
  }
}

let var = Enum::Var {
  field1: Some("aaa".to_string()),
  field2: None
}

match var {
  Enum::Var {field1, field2} => {
    match (field1, field2) {
      (Some("aaa".to_string()), None) => (),
      _ => panic!()
    }
  }
  _ => panic!()
}
```

However, I get the error message

```
error: expected one of `)`, `,`, `...`, `..=`, `..`, or `|`, found `.`
  --> src/parser/test_admonitions.rs:61:22
   |
61 |         (Some("aaa".to_string()), None) => {}
   |                      ^
   |                      |
   |                      expected one of `)`, `,`, `...`, `..=`, `..`, or `|`
   |                      help: missing `,`

error: aborting due to 1 previous error
```

Why is this? Why can't I match against a tuple?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why can't I match against a tuple?

You can match against a tuple.

What you can not do is match against arbitrary expressions, patterns are a restricted syntax.

The correct way to check that the first element of the tuple is `"aaa"` (or more generally matches a non-trivial condition) is to use a *pattern guard*:

```rust
match (field1, field2) {
    (Some(a), None) if a == "aaa" => (),
    _ => panic!()
}
```

furthermore the indirection through a tuple is not necessary, patterns have "depth" so you can do the same thing on the struct directly:

```rust
match var {
    Enum::Var {field1: Some(a), field2: None} if a == "aaa" => {
    }
    _ => panic!()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the match guard as shown my @Masklinn, you can use [`Option::as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) to convert `Option<String>` to `Option<&str>`, and match against the latter:

```
match var {
    Enum::Var { field1, field2 } => match (field1.as_deref(), field2.as_deref()) {
        (Some("aaa"), None) => (),
        _ => panic!(),
    },
}
```